# localStorage pagecount - show/hid div

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm struggelin' to get this to work.
Wan't to show specific div to people, based on amount of visits to my site.

```
var n = localStorage.getItem('on_load_count');
if (n === null) {
n = 0;
}
n++;
localStorage.setItem("on_load_count", n);

var v = localStorage.getItem('on_load_count'); 
if (v < "3" ) { 
document.querySelector('#myBox1').style.visibility = "visible";
document.querySelector('#myBox2').style.visibility = "hidden";
document.querySelector('#myBox3').style.visibility = "hidden";
} else if (v > "6" ) { 
document.querySelector('#myBox1').style.visibility = "hidden";
document.querySelector('#myBox2').style.visibility = "visible";
document.querySelector('#myBox3').style.visibility = "hidden";
} else if (v > "10" ) { 
document.querySelector('#myBox1').style.visibility = "hidden";
document.querySelector('#myBox2').style.visibility = "hidden";
document.querySelector('#myBox3').style.visibility = "visible";
} else { 
}
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the order of if conditions , big no count comes first to compare

```
if (v < 3 ) { 
document.querySelector('#myBox1').style.visibility = "visible";
document.querySelector('#myBox2').style.visibility = "hidden";
document.querySelector('#myBox3').style.visibility = "hidden";

 } else if (v > 10 ) { 
document.querySelector('#myBox1').style.visibility = "hidden";
document.querySelector('#myBox2').style.visibility = "hidden";
document.querySelector('#myBox3').style.visibility = "visible";

} else if (v > 6 ) { 
document.querySelector('#myBox1').style.visibility = "hidden";
document.querySelector('#myBox2').style.visibility = "visible";
document.querySelector('#myBox3').style.visibility = "hidden";
else { 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the string to integer `(v < 3 )`. `>` is not working with string

```
var n = localStorage.getItem('on_load_count');
if (n === null) {
n = 0;
}
n++;
localStorage.setItem("on_load_count", n);

var v = localStorage.getItem('on_load_count'); 
if (v < 3 ) { 
document.querySelector('#myBox1').style.visibility = "visible";
document.querySelector('#myBox2').style.visibility = "hidden";
document.querySelector('#myBox3').style.visibility = "hidden";
} else if (v > 6 ) { 
document.querySelector('#myBox1').style.visibility = "hidden";
document.querySelector('#myBox2').style.visibility = "visible";
document.querySelector('#myBox3').style.visibility = "hidden";
} else if (v > 10 ) { 
document.querySelector('#myBox1').style.visibility = "hidden";
document.querySelector('#myBox2').style.visibility = "hidden";
document.querySelector('#myBox3').style.visibility = "visible";
} else { 
}
```